# Properties of infimum and supremum of sets ( $ A_n \subset B_n \implies \liminf A_n \subset \liminf B_n$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove if $A_n \subset B_n$ for all $n$, then $\liminf A_n \subset \liminf B_n $ and $\limsup A_n \subset \limsup B_n$.

Attempt of proof:

1. $\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{n\ge1}\bigl(\bigcap_{k\ge n} A_k\bigr)$

$x \in \liminf A_n \implies \exists n: x \in \bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k \implies x \in A_k, \ \ k\ge n \implies x \in B_k, \ k \ge n \implies x\in \bigcap_{k \ge n}B_k$ and I am not sure what do now

2.$\limsup A_n=\bigcap_{n\ge1}\bigl(\bigcup_{k\ge =n}A_k\bigr)$

$x \in \limsup A_n \implies \forall n \ge 1: \ x\in \bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k \implies x \in \bigcup_{k \ge n}B_k$ and I am not sure what do now

Comment: Well, $x$ belongs to the union of the intersections and to the intersection of the unions (of the $B_k$s) respectively, and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done.

1. $\bigcap_{k\geq n} B_k\subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcap_{k\geq n} B_k$.
2. $\forall n \ge 1: \ x\in \bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k \implies \forall n \ge 1:~x \in \bigcup_{k \ge n}B_k\implies x\in\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}B_k$

Answer (score 2):

The set $\liminf_nA_n$ is the set of those elements that belong to all $A_n$, if $n$ is large enough. So $x\in\liminf_nA_n$ means that there is a natural $N$ such that $x\in A_n$ for each $n\geqslant N$. But then it is also true that $x\in B_n$ if $n\geqslant N$ and therefore $x\in\liminf_nB_n$.

The set $\limsup_nA_n$ is the set of those elemnts that belong to infinitely many $A_n$'s. But whenever $x\in A_n$, $x\in B_n$. Therefore, if $x$ belongs to infinitely many $A_n$'s, then $x$ belongs to infinitely many $B_n$'s too; in other words, $x\in\limsup_nB_n$.